# How do I load data from a external json api using angularJS?

Tags: json, angularjs

for example I want to view data from two urls:
1- http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/
2- http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/

Can I load data from these two url's in one app with two controllers in one view page?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$http.get` to issue the query ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q47070rn/)):

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
.controller('CtrlOne', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').then(function (data) {
        $scope.posts = data.data;
    });
}])
.controller('CtrlTwo', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/').then(function (data) {
        $scope.todos = data.data;
    });
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy">
    <div ng-controller="CtrlOne">{{ posts[0] | json }}</div>
    <div ng-controller="CtrlTwo">{{ todos[0] | json }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soulsurfer/q47070rn/1/
I've like updated your jsfiddle, my alteration doesn't seems to work, can you please explain me whats happening here? and change the jsfiddle.

Comment: @user2317954 Check the console to find error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.mvflights.com/arrivals/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. Well, it is another issue of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: ah thanks a lot, I'll look in to this issue right away.